# TFS task panel configuration with additional fields

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I am trying to recreate my own tfs with similar features. The additional fields for an item are **Effort(hours)**.

Is this an addon or does this require change in flow via visual studio? I think I have an idea but I forgot how is technology to edit TFS called and where in visual studio?

[image]

Comment: Please clarify: "my own tfs with similar features": do you mean your own *process* or are you re-creating TFS itself?

Comment: my own process. i have my own tfs account.

Comment: Probably the best route is to export (as XML) the current process and import as the new. That allows a process to be cloned. However if your version of TFS supports process inheritance start by creating a child process and modify that.

Answer (score 0):

The **Effort(hours)** in Task work item type is existing in AGILE and CMMI process Template. If you use Scrum template, you can change to the Agile template for your project.

You can use [Burndown in tasks](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/report/sql-reports/sprint-burndown-scrum) if you want to track how much work remains in a sprint backlog, understand how quickly your team has completed tasks, and predict when your team will achieve the goal or goals of the sprint.

We simply use number of tasks for our burndown measure. Usually you do something like actual hours or ideal hours, but this was good enough for us and apparently interesting enough to need some clarification.

There is a [**user voice**](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/2346623-update-how-effort-estimates-work-in-the-scrum-tfs) about using the effort estimates work in the Scrum TFS template for your reference (The response from TFS Product Group):

> The “Effort” field on the Product Backlog Item is meant to be any unit
>   the team decides they want to use. Some teams use “Story Points”. Some
>   use “Ideal Days”.
>
> The Remaining Work field on the Task, is the same think. It is
>   whatever the team decides it to be. The only thing our tools expect is
>   that it is reduced as you work on it, so we can provide a burn-down.
>
> If what you are looking for is a way to capture the original estimate
>   (complexity) of the task, then you’ll need to update the Task work
>   item type definition and add that custom field yourself.

If you need to custom field, please refer to [Add or modify a field](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/customize/add-modify-field) for details.

And this thread for your reference: [Scrum - When do you Estimate the Effort for Product Backlog Items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502731/scrum-when-do-you-estimate-the-effort-for-product-backlog-items)

Besides, you can also try the Addons : eg [TFS Time Tracker](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Berichthaus.TfsTimetracker)

Comment: @Amel Salibasic Have you resolved the issue by above workaround? any update?